# What exactly does document.normalize do?

Tags: javascript

I read that `document.normalize` **Removes empty Text nodes, and joins adjacent nodes**.

What does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Text node would be this:

```
<p>
  <span>foo</span>
  bar
</p>
```

`<p>` is a node, `<span>` is a node, so what is `"bar"`? → It's a text node.

Using the DOM API, it's possible to create empty text, or two adjacent text nodes:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement("div");

wrapper.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Part 1"));
wrapper.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Part 2"));
```

In HTML that would just be `<div>Part 1Part2</div>`, but to the DOM it's two separate text nodes, which is… weird.

[`Node.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) *normalises* this to get rid of such inefficient anomalies; it would merge both text nodes into one, and remove text nodes which are entirely empty.

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
p element
   text node containing ""
p element
   text node containing "Hello, "
   text node containing "world"
```

It will convert it to

```
p element
p element
   text node containing "Hello, world"
```

The text node inside the paragraph by itself, with no content, is removed entirely.

The two adjacent text nodes are joined together into a single text node with the combined text.

Comment: Can you add an html example to your answer please

Comment: Since HTML doesn't let you express text nodes explicitly: No, I can't.

Comment: So, how do they get there?